# How do I loop through a deeper json array with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, loops

I've looked through other questions on looping through arrays using the .each element, and I still can't get my function to work - I get reference errors on undefined elements and I imagine I'm just not going 'deep enough' in my nested .each statements.

My function returns on success a variable 'response', which should contain many objects/arrays.

```
$.each(response, function(){
     console.log(response.first_name);
}
```

This is obviously incorrect, as it doesn't go 'deep enough' so to speak, but I'm confused on how to add multiple $.each loops inside of it. Other questions have names listed where 'response' is or they have function(x, test) to show an index as they loop through. I'm lost.

My json is structured as such, according to the console in Google Chrome:

```
Object {data: Array[2]}
    data: Array[2]
        0: Object
            User: Object
                  first_name: "Steve"
                  last_name: "Ramsey"
        1: Object
            User: Object
                  first_name: "Bob"
                  last_name: "Ramsey"
```

As you can see, the name of one of the fields increments, so I know I need one variable as an index while looping through the number. The idea is that I'll then use this data to spit out 'Bob Ramsey', 'Steve Ramsey', etc. on the page along with any other information that could be in the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well `first_name` looks to be part of an object call `User` so you would need to reference User first.

```
var response = {
    data: [{
        User: {
            first_name: "Steve",
            last_name: "Ramsey"
        }
    },{
        User: {
            first_name: "Bob",
            last_name: "Ramsey"
        }
    }]
};

$.each(response.data, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value.User.first_name);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8LfXF/1/

Comment: Trying this gives me 'cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined.'

Comment: It still gives me the same error, for some reason. In my IDE 'index' is underlined saying it's unused, so I assume 'index' in this case autoincrements as part of the .each function?

Comment: Code runs fine for me. Is the object different than what I added above?

Comment: I tried hardcoding a number there, '0.User.first_name' and the error went away, but there was nothing returned as if the field was empty.

Comment: Maybe the object is made strangely. On yours there's no '0', '1', '2', etc. for each object in the array (one up from 'User').

Comment: The 0,1,2 is just chrome showing you the index in the console. Did you  change the each to look like mine? AKA `response.data`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. The '.data' was it - I must not have seen that the first time. It's working perfect!